# JavaScript Event Listeners inside methods

Tags: javascript

I was hoping to be able to call object methods from an event listener, however, I am unable to access object properties on the called function:

```
import {action} from '../desktopIntegration/actions.js'

class Object {
  constructor() {
    this.property = 2
  }

  addListener() {
     action.on("keyup", this.printEvent)
  }

  printEvent() {
    console.log(this.property)
  }

}
```

This code gives the error:

```
 unable to access property of undefined
```

when addListener is called.

Is there a way to make this work? I want to keep the callback as a method function so that I can delete the listener on each instance of Object.

Thanks!

Comment: You can bind it. `this.printEvent.bind(this)`.

Comment: shouldnt this.printEvent be  this.printEvent() ?

Comment: Note that you should NEVER call your class `Object`.

Comment: @Blaine: No. It is an assignment, not an execution.

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods are not bound to the class instance by default. If a method is being used as an event listener, it is by default bound to the **element** *emitting* the event.

To fix that, you need to overwrite your method in the `constructor`, by a version bound to the class instance:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.property = 2
    this.printEvent = this.printEvent.bind(this)
    this.addListener()
  }

  addListener() {
     document.getElementById('action').addEventListener("keyup", this.printEvent)
  }

  printEvent(event) { // added the event argument, gets automatically passed to the listener
    console.log(this.property)
    console.log(event.target.value) // to access the event emitting element, use event.target
  }

}

const bar = new Foo();
```

```html
<input id="action" />
```

Also note that you should **NEVER** call your class `Object`.